# ¿Como puedo poner un efecto hover sobre una parte del texto en el footer?

Tags: html, css, footer

Antes que nada muchas gracias por leer esta inquietud.
Abro esta pregunta ya que no estoy pudiendo poner el efecto hover sobre una parte de un texto.

Es decir tengo todo un texto y lo que quiero es que solo al posar en la palabra Doneldo se ponga con un hover de color negro.

```
<p>Hecho con <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
        <a href="www.google.com.ar" style="text-decoration: none; color: #777;">Doneldo<div class="txthover"> </a></div>
    </p>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4YRL.png]

---

[image: Adjunto codigo de mi HTML]

esa parte que tiene la flecha es la que quiero que al pasar el mouse (hover) se ponga de otro color

Comment: ¿Ya buscaste información acerca del selector `:hover`?

Comment: Hola! si,  hay informacion sobre hover, pero puntualmente el problema que tengo yo es que no se como poner como una subclase para decirle que esta parte del texto debe tener el efecto hover. y no todo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Donde esta el error, te explico las etiquetas o elementos están rotos, lo estas poniendo de esta forma `<a>   <div>   </a>   </div>`; cuando deberían estar así `<a>   <div>   </div>   </a>`.
.

Como hacer lo que quieres; encierra el texto "Doneldo" dentro de un `<span> </span>`.

```css
a { text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    }
    
.txthover:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<p>Hecho con <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
      <a href="www.google.com.ar"><span class="txthover">Doneldo</span></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Fantastico Andres, muchas gracias por tu ayudar!